# "Stoic" as an adjective and "stoical"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ic-ical

In common speech, I often hear *stoic* used as an adjective. (I am ignoring definitions related to Stoicism.)

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic) validates this use with the definition "not affected by or showing passion or feeling." It also gives *stoical* as a variant.

Meanwhile, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stoic) only calls the adjective "another form for stoical." It defines *stoical* as "enduring pain and hardship without showing one's feelings or complaining," which matches Merriam-Webster's definition of *stoic*.

I understand words can have multiple accepted variations of spelling, but the difference between *stoic* and *stoical* seems more than just spelling.

If these two major dictionaries disagree about which form is more standard, which one actually is? The idea that *stoic* is only a noun and *stoical* its adjective form, as suggested by the Oxford dictionary, makes sense but conflicts with common usage. If the common choice of *stoic*, supported by Merriam-Webster, is correct, why does the Oxford dictionary defer it to *stoical*?

Perhaps this is simply an issue of personal preference, but I am at least curious about reasons one form may be preferred over the other.

Comment: You may be interested in looking at some of the other questions about ["-ic" vs. "-ical"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ic-ical?sort=votes&pageSize=30)

Comment: @sumelic I didn't even realize this was a common issue for other words. Thank you.

Comment: An unscientific survey of Americans and Brits at the breakfast table unanimously goes with stoic as an adjective. All would say "They are stoic" and not "They're a stoic".  So we actually construct sentences to use it as an adjective and avoid the noun usage. And *Stoical* just got blank stares.

Comment: 'Ignoring definitions related to Stoicism' is impossible in this context, as the meanings of these word in English are **all** related to Stoicism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stoic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stoic) is a commonly  accepted alternative spelling to [stoical](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stoical&allowed_in_frame=0). "***The adjective ([stoic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stoic)) is recorded from 1590s** in the "repressing feelings" sense, c. 1600 in the philosophical sense*". (Etymonline)

> - of or relating to the school of philosophy founded by Zeno, who taught that people should be free from passion, unmoved by joy or grief, and submit without complaint to unavoidable necessity.
> - (lowercase) stoical.

(Dictionary.com)

The following  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very%20stoic%2Cvery%20stoical%2C%20so%20stoic%2C%20so%20stoical&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20stoic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20stoical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20stoic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20stoical%3B%2Cc0) search appears to suggest that the adjective stoic is becoming more common than stoical.

Comment: It looks like *stoical* predates *stoic*, which became an accepted variant some decades later?

Comment: @Zach - Yes, and  both usages are centuries old.

Answer (score -3):

Uneducated usage eventually becomes accepted and then educated usage (sadly.. for the French spirit in me).

But I always use stoical as an adjective and stoic as a noun. I trust my Oxford dictionary of more than 30 years' partnership over anything else. ('Stoic, n. Definition: stoical person'). It drives me bonkers when people get it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is a comment, not an answer. You will be able to comment when you have 50 rep (gained from writing good answers). Unfortunately it's also mistaken. OED does have *stoic* as an adjective.